# Repointing and rebuilding address locators?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geocoding

I have a few ArcGIS address locators that originally used data from a file geodatabase.  I would like to repoint these locators to the same layers in an enterprise geodatabase instead.  Additionally, as these layers are sometimes edited, I would like to create a script to automatically rebuild the locators to reflect the changes.  I was able to manually repoint the locator data sources to the enterprise geodatabase.  However, every time I attempt to rebuild, I get the error "The address locator needs to be repaired in order to be rebuilt.  Do you want to proceed with repair?"  When I say ok, it opens the locator's properties with a red X next to the data source (which is in the format Database Connections\MyDatabase.sde\fileName).  I will manually repoint it to that exact same data source.  It will be fine with that, allow the rebuild, and the updated features will appear in the locator.  However, the next time I try to rebuild, same issue.

If I try to use the Rebuild Address Locator tool in ArcMap, it says Error 000005: Could not open the address locator.  Then if I try to rebuild or open the address locator, it will say that it can't open the address locator because it was made in ArcMap 9.2 or earlier (it wasn't, it was made in 10.3).  This appears to permanently break it and all I can do is delete it and recreate it.  This happens even when I stop the services that use the locator and make sure all relevant files are closed.

I am able to successfully rebuild the address locators manually, and it will work.  However, I'd like to be able to automate this process so that the locators will be rebuilt whenever the source data is updated.  Everything works fine when using the data from the file geodabase but the problems start when I switch to the enterprise geodatabase.  The address locators are located on the C drive of the server where the geocoding services are published.  The file geodatabase is also on the C drive in the same folder (but the locators aren't in the geodatabase).  The enterprise database is in the Database Connections on the same server.

Do I need to move data around or use different file paths?

Comment: looks like this is not possible  a long thread comes to 'corruption' conclusion even when arcpy scripting is used. >  https://community.esri.com/thread/26603